# HTML, CSS: Using pseudo element to insert image in a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a copy of an Olympic rank, and I'm stuck on the part where putting the flag before the name of the country.(Must use pseudo element) [image]

I'm still doing Norway and this is the first tablerow

```
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noc"><div>Norway</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

and here's the css

```
.noc > div::before{
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
}
```

if we just put the image url inside `content=""', it works but unable to change size of the image. So if I use` background-image` instead, the whole image is gone. Here's the result.
[image]

And also, like the original rank table on the website, the column border is hidden, but when I try to hide like this, `border-style:none` `display:none` to my `td` , all of the borders were gone. Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo element is a useful way of adding this visual clue to the table.

The problem with your code is that the dimensions of the flag are not being picked up.

Add `display: inline-block` to the pseudo element.

In addition, you want the contents of that cell to be vertically aligned so this snippet makes it flex with `align-items: center`. This makes the text and the flag align vertically.

```css
.noc>div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.noc>div::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noc">
      <div>Norway</div>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your CSS Like

```
.noc>div::before {
        content: "";
        background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
        background-size: 22px 22px;
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```css
.noc > div::before{
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  padding-left: 27px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noc"><div>Norway</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works, but the flag only shows half an image..

Comment: Will you please explain little bit about what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to put images in before pseudo selector here, but try giving it a `position: absolute;` with top and left equal to 0. it might help.

Comment: Why isn't a good idea?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode entities, there's a pictograph character for every country flag. At the bottom of the `<head>` place this tag:

```
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Next, add the following to CSS (the exact lengths may very depending on other styles you may have)

```
.em {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin-top: -3.5px
}
```

Then for each `<td>` in the second column, follow this pattern:

```
<td><i class='em em-flag-'></i> Full Name of Country</td>
```

<sup>This stylesheet provides the flag icons. For details, go to:
https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/</sup>
 <sup>This is a ISO Alpha-2 Country Code. Refer to: https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm</sup>

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font-size: 3ch
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey
}

td {
  padding: 2.5px 5px
}

.em {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin-top: -3.5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table>
  <tr><td><i class='em em-flag-no'></i> Norway</td></tr>
  <tr><td><i class='em em-flag-de'></i> Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td><i class='em em-flag-cn'></i> People's Republic of China</td></tr>
  <tr><td><i class='em em-flag-us'></i> United States of America</td></tr>
</table>
```

The Unicode flags only show as ISO Alpha-2 (ex. US, DE, GB, etc) for Windows OS. Using the CSS pseudo-elements with the Unicode would only show a flag image for 68% of the world's users. Here's an example<sup>✺</sup>:

```css
td::before {
  content: '\01f1e8\01f1f3 ';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td> People's Republic of China</td></tr>
</table>
```

<sup>✺ The CSS Unicodes can be found at: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/flag Locate the dropdown button to the right of the search bar and select CSS option</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `span` for flag. also in the below code, I used `border-bottom` and `border-top` for `td` and `border-collapse: collapse` for `table`, so only horizontally borders are displayed. I used two `tr` to you see borders:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
.noc>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noc"><span></span>
      <div>Norway</div>
    </td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noc"><span></span>
      <div>Norway</div>
    </td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;` in pseudo element for centering the FLAG. `.noc` is common and use shortname of countries as second class for `FLAG` like `(nor, ger, chn ....)`.

I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```css
table{width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td{border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px; text-align: left;}

/* ----- */
.noc>div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.noc>div::before{
    content: '';
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.nor>div::before{
    background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/NOR.png");
}
.ger>div::before{
    background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/GER.png");
}
.chn>div::before{
    background-image: url("https://olympics.com/beijing-2022/olympic-games/static/common/img/flags/CHN.png");
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="70">Order</th>
            <th colspan="2">NOC</th>
            <th>-</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="noc nor">
                <div>Norway</div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="noc ger">
                <div>Germany</div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="noc chn">
                <div>People's Republic of China</div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```